# using regex to select a string pattern not containing a word

Tags: php, html, regex

how could I select from this string made of 3 image markup the ones not containing ?

```
 id="img_menu":
```

string:

```
 <img class="alignnone " blabla />
  <img class="dddd " blabla />
 <img  style="blalbla"  id="img_menu"/>
```

this regex select all markups :

```
    /<img*[^>]*[^>]./
```

but i did not manage to  add the proper code to select out the 3rd img ! please help.

Comment: There's nothing in your regex telling it to exclude the third string. Also, your regex is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, though the lookarounds aren't my strong point, so there may be a more efficient way of doing it:

**JS**

```
var str = '<img class="alignnone " blabla />\n\
<img class="dddd " blabla />\n\
<img  style="blalbla"  id="img_menu"/>';
str.match(/(?!<img.+?id="img_menu".*?\/>)<img.+?\/>/g);
//["<img class="alignnone " blabla />", "<img class="dddd " blabla />"]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhepM/)

**PHP**

```
<?php
$code = '<img class="alignnone " blabla />
<img class="dddd " blabla />
<img  style="blalbla"  id="img_menu"/>';
$newStr = preg_replace('/(?!<img.+?id="img_menu".*?\/>)<img.+?\/>/','[matched_img]',$code);
var_dump(htmlentities($newStr));
?>
```

Output:

```
string(92) "[matched_img] [matched_img] <img style="blalbla" id="img_menu"/>"
```

Comment: i forgot to say i'd like to make it working using php preg_replace('myregex','',mystring)

Comment: @Matoeil Sorry! My fault - didn't check the tags. Will update.

Comment: that would be really nice of u

Comment: that is working beautifully !! i am very grateful , i have spent hours on that

Comment: @Matoeil No worries - glad to have helped

Answer (score 2):

Use multi-line/not-dot-all mode in a while/global loop.

```
 ^(?!.*id=\"img_menu\").*$
```

You can do this because its only a string and not html.

Comment: sorry i don't understand that

Comment: This is a regex. What don't you understand?

Comment: this is the best answer. You can use it like this: `$pattern = '/^(?!.*id=\"img_menu\").*$/';`, then `preg_match($pattern, '<img  style="blalbla"  id="img_menu"/>' )`. This will return false.

Comment: @sln dunno..it does not work in my hands !? but i appreciate your help

Comment: @Matoeil - Just a FYI., 'multi-line' mode and 'dot-all' mode and  global mode are on the first page of 'regex basics' tutorials. That's a good starting point to learn regex.